# Start new task with predefined backstack (activity B ontop of activity A)

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to start a task with an activity B in the foreground but with an activity A on the backstack? So when I start B via intent and press the back or home button A is active.

At the moment I can start a new task via intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and start B but of course my backstack is empty so when I hit the back button it will return to the home screen.

Only if the app was running before (activity A already exists). Starting activity B will result in the correct backstack state A,B where B in ontop of A.

Comment: what u exactly want to do like app start -> activity A -> activity B -> (onbackpress) -> activity A.  like u want to this

Comment: When sending data from a third party app my activity C has an intent listener and should directly start my app in a new task with B in front of A.

Comment: remove  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK when u come from A to B

Comment: I got this scenario covered: app start -> activity A -> activity B -> (onbackpress) -> activity A. Now I want to do this: third party app -> (send data) -> activity C -> (start new task) -> activity B -> (onbackpress) -> activity A

Comment: have u done it dude :)

Comment: Simply start activity A from activity B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when u backpress from that condition then set one `flag boolean` and whenever u backpress then check that falg if true then in back button hust pass Activity intent for A :)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I used `Activity.isTaskRoot()` in activity B to check if A has to be started on back button press.